# Can not enable Costum Helth Prob for Azure App gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I deploy a application Gateway on Azure, but Backend health say "unknown" as satus all the time.

If I request via

```
Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHealth -Name $appGwName -ResourceGroupName $myRg
```

I receive

```
"BackendHttpSettings": {
    "ProbeEnabled": false,
    "Id": "/subscriptions/XXX"
},
"Servers": [
    {
        "Address": "X.X.X.X",
        "Health": "Unknown"
    }
]
```

But I did not find a way to activate the probe. I created the probe via Portal and via powershell, in both cases I run into the same Problem.

```
$helthProbe01 = New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -Name "httpsProbe" -Protocol Https -HostName "127.0.0.1" -Path "/page/index.aspx" -Interval 30 -Timeout 60 -UnhealthyThreshold 3
```

How can I activate the Health probe?

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This properties can **Flag if probe should be enabled, not the status of the probe**.

But,whether the probe is enabled, Default value is false. So, it means that it does nothing about whether your probe is active.

> Backend health say "unknown" as satus all the time.

1. Ensure you have configure all settings correctly, you can refer to this document to add a probe to your Applicaiton gateway.
2. Don't use the IP address like `127.0.0.1` as your hostname, please add a hostname which can be access from public Network.

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI, I think you forgot to add the document link. 
For 127.0.01: As far as I understand https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502 this should be Default and meaning the target itself.

Comment: Hi, @DanielW.    Um... Thanks for your reminder. But this is the URL of default Probe which configured by backend HTTP settings ,NOT custom probe which created by yourself. I'm not sure whether it also works for custom probe.